# How to make one row from result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting following result by using my store procedure. How would I get only one line of result after eliminate the nulls. ?

```
`cte_Sum
as
(
Select sum(NumberOfCode) as NumberOfCode, CodeName, Code, Quarters, Q1s, Q2s, Q3s, Q4s  
from cte_totals 
group by CodeName, Code, Quarters, Q1s, Q2s, Q3s, Q4s 
)
Select 
CodeName,Code, 
Case When Quarters = 'Q1' Then NumberOfCode End  as Q1_Number,
Case When Quarters = 'Q1' Then Q1s End  as Q1_Date, 
Case When Quarters = 'Q2' Then NumberOfCode End  as Q2_Number,
Case When Quarters = 'Q2' Then Q2s End  as Q2_Date,  
Case When Quarters = 'Q3' Then NumberOfCode End  as Q3_Number,
Case When Quarters = 'Q3' Then Q3s End  as Q3_Date, 
Case When Quarters = 'Q4' Then NumberOfCode End  as Q4_Number,
Case When Quarters = 'Q4' Then Q4s End  as Q4_Date
from cte_Sum`
```

[image: Result]

Expected result. 
[image]

Comment: select max() on all those attributes

Comment: Thanks, It works

Comment: Thanks all, I used max to fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
Select CodeName, Code, 
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q1' Then NumberOfCode End) as Q1_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q1' Then Q1s End)  as Q1_Date, 
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q2' Then NumberOfCode End)  as Q2_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q2' Then Q2s End)  as Q2_Date,  
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q3' Then NumberOfCode End)  as Q3_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q3' Then Q3s End)  as Q3_Date, 
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q4' Then NumberOfCode End)  as Q4_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q4' Then Q4s End)  as Q4_Date
from cte_Sum
group by CodeName, Code;
```

I don't think the CTE helps.  You can also do:

```
Select CodeName, Code, 
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q1' Then NumberOfCode else 0 End) as Q1_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q1' Then Q1s End)  as Q1_Date, 
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q2' Then NumberOfCode else 0 End)  as Q2_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q2' Then Q2s End)  as Q2_Date,  
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q3' Then NumberOfCode else 0 End)  as Q3_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q3' Then Q3s End)  as Q3_Date, 
       sum(Case When Quarters = 'Q4' Then NumberOfCode else 0 End)  as Q4_Number,
       max(Case When Quarters = 'Q4' Then Q4s End)  as Q4_Date
from cte_totals
group by CodeName, Code;
```

You may also be able to simplify out the `cte_totals` as well, although your question doesn't show that code.

Comment: I think you want max, not sum. :)

Comment: @SeanLange . . . It doesn't make a difference for the first version, but `sum()` makes more sense for simplifying the logic.

Comment: But some of those are dates and sum on a date doesn't make much sense.

Comment: you can't do sum on date. I aggree with Sean.

Answer (score 0):

I will self left join with itself for those lines where Q2 - Q4 columns are not NULL.

```
select t1.CodeName ,t1.Code , 
Q2.Q2_NUmber, Q2.Q2_DAte, 
Q3.Q3_NUmber, Q3.Q3_DAte, 
Q4.Q4_NUmber, Q4.Q4_DAte
from table t1
left join (select Code, Q2_Number, Q2_Date where Q2_Number is not NULL) Q2 on t1.Code = Q2.Code      
left join (select Code, Q3_Number, Q3_Date where Q3_Number is not NULL) Q3 on t1.Code = Q3.Code
left join (select Code, Q4_Number, Q4_Date where Q4_Number is not NULL) Q4 on t1.Code = Q4.Code
```